# Get list of database names using psql

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to get a list of database names using the `psql` command. So far I have:

```
psql -h example.com -U backup -c '\l'
```

This however gives me the results in a table-like format. I ONLY want the table names (one on each line). How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This does it:

```
psql -h example.com -U backup -t -A -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname <> ALL ('{template0,template1,postgres}')"
```

Using the system catalog [`pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-database.html).

Read [the manual about psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: I would add `where datname not in ('template0', 'template1', 'postgres')`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can use `\l` for that.

But the following should do it:

```
psql -h example.com -U backup -t -c "select datname from pg_database"
```

`\t` turns off the header and the other "noise". And the select statement only returns the database name.

Not sure if you need to use single quotes or double quotes for the SQL statement - on my Windows console I had to use double quotes.